# Download and compress multiple URLs into a single zip archive using Javascript(s)

Tags: javascript

I've been searching through various threads trying to find a method that allows me to download and compress files from a URL list into a ZIP archive and once done, save it to a folder of user choice.

I've found some half finished attempts to do similar things, but it seems everything I find is limited to images(supposedly re-encodes jpg-images thus lowering quality), assumes that the file is already available on the users computer for archiving or is stored on the same host.

I need to be able to add files of any format into an archive from a list of URLs without loss of quality. Or fetching the URL to each file from within a div element.

I wish I had an initiative example code, but I've found nothing that represents what I need so I have nothing to paste as an example. I am avoiding PHP, trying to keep strictly to Javascript and JS-function libraries.

Have a good day

Comment: did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @liz_ophiuchus No, I never found a solution. I had to give up for the moment. I'll probably look into it again once I have time